# how to change div heights based on resize with scrolling included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've run into an issue where I need 2 divs height to fill up the screen based on resize no matter what the browser dimensions/resolution etc with scrolling included.

Right now without javascript it takes the height based on the body,html with min-height. Which is great! Except when you resize to a smaller size and then scroll downwards. You end up with whitespace. 
For this example I have two divs side by side. Both 50%. Column1 is with black background color, and Column2 is with a white background color. I've gone and added some javascript and every-time I resize it just keeps adding extra height and the scrollbar becomes incredibly large.

Image one shows it regular. 
[image: image1]
Image two shows it after resizing a little bit. A ton of extra height is added. notice the scrollbar
[image: image2]

Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="panelWrapper">
      <div id="column1">
      </div>
      <div id="column2">
      </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html { 
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
}

#panelWrapper {
width:100%;
position: absolute;
}

#column1{
position:absolute;
width:50%;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
min-width: 481px;
background-color: #000000;
}

#column2{
position:absolute;
width:50%;
left:50%;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
z-index: 999;
min-width: 481px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var bodyheight = $(document).height();
$("#column1, #column2").height(bodyheight);

$(window).resize(function() {
var bodyheight = $(document).height();
$("#column1, #column2").height(bodyheight);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep both divs filling up the height, no matter what size of each other, you don't even need Javascript...

The JS `resize` event is heavy, and there are many css-only solutions for that.

For example, you could make your `#panelWrapper` a `display: table`, and have the column divs to be `display: table-cell`. That would ensure that they are the same height.

Then, a `min-height: 100%` on the wrapper would make sure that they always fill up the remaining space when needed:

Here's a [**simple example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wb9knzep/) showing the concept.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to test this on a fiddle but try this out, it should work. You can wrap everything in a function and just call the function on resize:

```
function adjustHeight(){
  var bodyHeight = $(document).height();
  $("#column1, #column2").height(bodyHeight);
}

adjustHeight(); //call on page load

$(window).resize(adjustHeight); //call on resize
```